# Recordset repeat region in drop down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, recordset

I am trying to get all my archive links (feb 2012, march 2012 etc..) to work in a drop down menu. I have it displaying and linking to the most recent month but it won't display the other months in the drop down menu.
This is the code I have for the drop down menu:

```
      <h3>Archives</h3>
  <form name="form" id="form">
    <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
      <option value="#">-- Select Archive Date --</option>
      <option value="archive.php?archive=<?php echo $row_getArchives['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getArchives['archive']; ?></option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

Is there any way I am able to dynamically show the rest of the months.

Here is a screenshot of basically what it looks like at the moment
 [image: Here is a screenshot of basically what it looks like at the moment]

Edit: This is the code I have for the recordsets (that is getting the data from the database)

```
$maxRows_getArchives = 10;
$pageNum_getArchives = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getArchives'])) {
  $pageNum_getArchives = $_GET['pageNum_getArchives'];
}
$startRow_getArchives = $pageNum_getArchives * $maxRows_getArchives;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getArchives = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %Y') AS archive, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%Y-%m') AS link FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC";
$query_limit_getArchives = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getArchives, $startRow_getArchives, $maxRows_getArchives);
$getArchives = mysql_query($query_limit_getArchives, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getArchives = mysql_fetch_assoc($getArchives);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getArchives'])) {
  $totalRows_getArchives = $_GET['totalRows_getArchives'];
} else {
  $all_getArchives = mysql_query($query_getArchives);
  $totalRows_getArchives = mysql_num_rows($all_getArchives);
}
$totalPages_getArchives = ceil($totalRows_getArchives/$maxRows_getArchives)-1;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getRecent = "SELECT news.post_id, news.title FROM news ORDER BY news.post_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$getRecent = mysql_query($query_getRecent, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getRecent = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRecent);
$totalRows_getRecent = mysql_num_rows($getRecent);

$maxRows_getDisplay = 1;
$pageNum_getDisplay = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getDisplay'])) {
  $pageNum_getDisplay = $_GET['pageNum_getDisplay'];
}
$startRow_getDisplay = $pageNum_getDisplay * $maxRows_getDisplay;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT  news.post_id, news.title,  DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC";
$query_limit_getDisplay = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getDisplay, $startRow_getDisplay, $maxRows_getDisplay);
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_limit_getDisplay, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getDisplay'])) {
  $totalRows_getDisplay = $_GET['totalRows_getDisplay'];
} else {
  $all_getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay);
  $totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($all_getDisplay);
}
$totalPages_getDisplay = ceil($totalRows_getDisplay/$maxRows_getDisplay)-1;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getPosts = "SELECT post_id, title, updated FROM news ORDER BY updated DESC";
$getPosts = mysql_query($query_getPosts, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPosts);
$totalRows_getPosts = mysql_num_rows($getPosts);

$queryString_getDisplay = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_getDisplay") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_getDisplay") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_getDisplay = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_getDisplay = sprintf("&totalRows_getDisplay=%d%s", $totalRows_getDisplay, $queryString_getDisplay);

$queryString_getArchives = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_getArchives") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_getArchives") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_getArchives = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_getArchives = sprintf("&totalRows_getArchives=%d%s", $totalRows_getArchives, $queryString_getArchives);



$var1_getDisplay2 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['archive'])) {
  $var1_getDisplay2 = $_GET['archive'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.post_id, news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y'), news. AS formatted FROM news WHERE DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%Y-%%m') = %s ORDER BY news.updated DESC", GetSQLValueString($var1_getDisplay2, "text"));
} elseif (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
  $var2_getDisplay3 = $_GET['post_id'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.post_id, news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted FROM news WHERE news.post_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($var2_getDisplay3, "int"));
} else {
  $query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.post_id, news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT ".$pageNum_getDisplay.", 5";
}
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
$totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($getDisplay);
?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `$row_getArchives['link']` from. database? if so how? Can you post the code. if this is coming form database, just use a `while loop`

Comment: @ROYFinley I edited my original post to show the recordset code that grabs the data from thee database

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just have to move some of the code to this:

```
  <form name="form" id="form">
      <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
        <option value="#">-- Select Archive Date --</option>
            <?php do { ?>
        <option value="archive.php?archive=<?php echo $row_getArchives['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getArchives['archive']; ?></option>
        <?php } while ($row_getArchives = mysql_fetch_assoc($getArchives)); ?>
      </select>
  </form>
```